# Android studio action-bar in custom activities

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have an app using `Navigation Drawer Activity` template, the issue is: default fragments(activities) all have action bar but my custom made activities not showing any action bar just the title.

## Screenshot

`Default main Fragment`

[image: one]

`custom made fragment`

[image: two]

## Code

`styles.xml`

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/customActionBarColor</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/customActionBarDarkColor</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/customAccentColor</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

`MainActivity`

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        val fab: FloatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.fab)
        fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show()
        }
        val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_services, R.id.nav_tools
            ), drawerLayout
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }
```

`HomeFragment`

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        homeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)

        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)

        recyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.categoriesRecycle)

        callAPIDemo()
        return root
    }
```

`My custom activity`

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_posts)
    callAPIDemo()
}
```

**Any idea why is that?**

> PS: If you need more code please don't hesitate to ask I will share what you need.

Answer (score 0):

foloow step in your activity
1.
To add custom action bar in activity first get actionbar using getSupportaActionBar().

2.
then set attribute getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

3.
and create one custom actionbar layout wich you want now add layout in actionbar using
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.your_layout);

that's  it it will inflate custom layout in your action bar.

Answer (score 0):

You should call ***code below*** for custom activity (ies) too

```
 val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
```

Also your xml should for custom activity should contain same view with `R.id.toolbar` Id